# Get clicked MenuStrip Item in C#

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, menustrip

I want to get the name of the clicked `MenuStrip` Item to start other Forms depending of the name.

I tried this so far but it don't work:

```
private void menu_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
    ToolStripMenuItem mi = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;
    ToolStripItem menuItem = sender as ToolStripItem;
    if(menuItem!= null)
    {

        ContextMenuStrip owner = menuItem.Owner as ContextMenuStrip;
        if(owner!= null)
        {
            Control sourceControl = owner.SourceControl;
        }
    }

}
```

mi and menuItem are both null. Can anyone explain me how to get the name of that item?

Comment: The control clicked is a MenuItem, Comobox or Textbox?

Comment: Try `e.ClickedItem`.

Comment: @LarsTech i tried it but again null

Comment: Then you have things mixed up.  Try using the click event for the menu item.

Comment: Have you tried "var menuItem = e.ClickedItem as ToolStripMenuItem"?

Comment: I'm using menu_ItemClicked. Isn't that what I want? what click event do I have to use?

Comment: Your cast isnt working because you are tryng to convert a MenuStrip(sender) to a ToolStripMenuItem.

Comment: No, ItemClicked is only for the parent items in the MenuStrip, not the dropped down items.  Each menu item should have it's own event handler wired up.

Comment: @LarsTech how do I do it? I thought I would get the menuitem name from menu_ItemClicked event.

Comment: In the designer, double-click on each menu item.

Comment: @LarsTech yes! it was so easy! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are clicking on the menustrip itself. Double click on the item on the menu or to generate an event like this.

```
private void menu_ItemClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var itemText = (sender as ToolStripMenuItem).Text;
    MessageBox.Show(itemText);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
private void contextMenuStrip1_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.ClickedItem.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way :

```
private void contextMenuStrip_Click(object sender, Eventargs e)
{
    ((System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip)(sender)).GetItemAt(((System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)(e)).X, ((System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)(e)).Y).Text 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the selected menuItem on a menu stripe one can do as follows:

```
private void menuStrip1_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
    string itemText = e.ClickedItem.Text;


    switch (itemText)
    {
        case "menu name 1":
            //do stuff
            break;

        case "menu name 2":
            // do stuff
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
private void menuStrip1_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
    string itemText = e.ClickedItem.Text;


    switch (itemText)
    {
        case "menu name 1":
            //do stuff
            break;

        case "menu name 2":
            // do stuff
            break;
    }
}
```